# How to dissable DependencyProperty callback

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, dependency-properties

How to disable calling callback methods in MyDP1_Changed and MyDP1_Changed? 
I need dissable callback when I change value from other callback method

```
class MyDependencyObject : DependencyObject
{

        public object MyDP1 {
           get{ return GetValue(MyDP1Property); }
           set{ return SetValue(MyDP1Property, value); }
        }

        public object MyDP2 {
           get{ return GetValue(MyDP2Property); }
           set{ return SetValue(MyDP2Property, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDP1Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyDP1", typeof(object), typeof(MyDependencyObject )
            , new UIPropertyMetadata(MyDP1_Changed));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDP2Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyDP2", typeof(object), typeof(MyDependencyObject )
            , new UIPropertyMetadata(MyDP2_Changed));

        private static void MyDP1_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            d.SetValue(MyDP2Property, e.NewValue);
        }

        private static void MyDP2_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            d.SetValue(MyDP1Property, e.OldValue);
        }
}
```

Comment: if you want to mantain both properties with the same values always...why dont use just 1 property?

Comment: A `PropertyChangedCallback` is only ever called when a property value *actually* changes. Your problem here seems to be a typo in `MyDP2_Changed`. It should probably set `e.NewValue` instead of `e.OldValue`. Then there would be no infinite recursion.

Comment: It is simple example. I need dissable callback when I change value from other callback method

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't make sense. Set a boolean flag if really needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK firstly, you need to use `SetCurrentValue` not `SetValue` - otherwise you'll blow your bindings.

Secondly, you can use these methods to temporarily add and remove callbacks

```
TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(d)["MyDP1"].RemoveValueChanged(d, MyDP1_Changed)

TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(d)["MyDP1"].AddValueChanged(d, MyDP1_Changed)
```